# Autocovariance and independent increments of Gaussian process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ...$ are iid normal RVs with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. Define the process
$$ Y_n = Y_{n-1} + X_n$$.

for integers $n \geq 1$ and with $Y_0 = 0$. I want to compute the auto-covariance of $Y_n$ and show that $\{Y_n\}$ is an independent increment process.

I wanted to proceed with the definition for the autocovariance and using the fact that $X_i$ are iid with mean 0
\begin{align}
R_Y(m,k) &= E((Y_{m-1} - X_m)(Y_{k-1} - X_k)) \\
&=E(Y_{m-1}Y_{k-1}  - Y_{m-1}X_n - Y_{n-1}X_m + X_m X_n) \\
&=E(Y_{m-1}Y_{k-1})  - E(Y_{m-1}X_n) - E(Y_{n-1}X_m) + E(X_m) E(X_n)\\
&=E(Y_{m-1}Y_{k-1})  - E(Y_{m-1}X_n) - E(Y_{n-1}X_m) 
\end{align}

Any hint on how to compute the left expectations? Also regarding showing the independent increments, the definition that I need to show is that for every $i < j$, $Y_i$ and $Y_{j} - Y_{i}$ are independent. I can't think of what definition of independence to use in this situation. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is known in the econometric literature as a (non-stationary) AR(1) process or more probabilistically as a Random Walk.

First we notice, by recursion, that $Y_n = Y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. Hnece

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y_n] := Y_0
$$

For the autocovariance, we need to compute

$$
\mathbb{E}[(Y_n - Y_0)(Y_{n-j}-Y_0)] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \bigg)\bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{n-j}X_k \bigg) \bigg] \\
= \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{n-j}X_{i}^{2} + \sum_{k \ne i}X_iX_k \bigg] = \text{by independence} \\
= \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{n-j}X_{i}^{2} \bigg] = (n-j) \sigma^2
$$

to prove the independence of the increments, we just need to notice that $Y_n -Y_{n-1} = X_n$. Thus the independence follows from the IID property of the $X_i$